# Crystal Report Referencing Issue in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have cloned a `git` project and I am having issue in running the project solution due to missing assembly issue of `Crystal Report`.

In my `web.config`:

```
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=myToken" />
```

[image]

I have included `CrystalDecisions` in my project references.

[image]

And I have set the properties from `False` to `True` for both references.

[image]

I have tried removing the existing references and added new references.

Ultimately, I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the [Crystal Report VS](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads) which leads me to another installation issue:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what is the solution?

Comment: Restore nuget pakages , Make sure compatible

Comment: Could you be more specify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who's experiencing the same issue as me, you have to install `CRRuntime_64bit_13_0` first and restart your computer for the changes to be applied. Then, you install `CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_20`. The resources can be found [here](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads).

You have to adjust according to the assembly file version that you have stated in your `web.config`. In my case, I'm using `Version=13.0.2000.0`